# Session ID changes when I make a POST request in Rails but only during tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, csrf, rspec-rails

I'm having a rather odd issue in that POST requests triggered by `link_to` with `method: :post`. In the test environment the `session_id` seems to change. This causes issues such as the current_user object doesn't exist within the action I'm posting too. I've logged out the request and the session info and I can see that the session has changed for the POST action and when I try to use current_user the test fails.

I have other POST requests through forms around the app. And they work fine. It seems to be some Rails magic around the `link_to` with `method: :post` and passing the CSRF token.

I'm able to get around this by changing my `test.rb` to be the same as my `development.rb`. But I'm sure this isn't a good solution. It's possible it's related to some configuration but it seems like this is the default behavior.

**Controller**

```
class RecruitersController < ApplicationController
  before_action -> { STDOUT.puts "Request: #{request.method} #{request.fullpath}" }
  before_action -> { STDOUT.puts "Session: #{session[:session_id]}" }

  ...
end
```

**Button that triggers the POST Request**

```
= link_to "<3", recruiter_request_url(id: recruiter.id), method: :post, remote: true
```

**Output in Tests**

```
Request: GET /recruiters/dashboard
Session: ee8c577fdf6d1714c2a837f0890e0294
Request: GET /recruiters/premium
Session: ee8c577fdf6d1714c2a837f0890e0294
Request: POST /recruiters/request_premium_trial/1
Session: 314c6eef0156aa36a469a4f9ea7513a8
```

**Output in Development**

```
Request: GET /recruiters/dashboard
Session: cdb333efb5d62e6ddbb5914c8edd7a92
Request: GET /recruiters/premium
Session: cdb333efb5d62e6ddbb5914c8edd7a92
Request: POST /recruiters/request_premium_trial/1
Session: cdb333efb5d62e6ddbb5914c8edd7a92
```

**The Spec** 
Simple spec user signs in goes to the dashboard, goes to the premium page and then clicks on the link that makes the POST request.

```
scenario 'Should be able to make request', js:true do
  rsign_in # Function that simulates sign in
  click_on 'Premium'
  click_on '<3'
  assert_text 'Request made' # Fails as we're redirected to sign in page when we try to authenticate the user
end
```

**Test.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Set log level
  config.log_level = :debug

  # This means that all URLs need to have 5 parts to them. This is for http://recruiter.127.0.0.1.xip.io:3000
  config.action_dispatch.tld_length = 5
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  cache_store = :file_store, "tmp/cache"
  # Use a different job queue
  config.active_job.queue_adapter = Figaro.env.job_queue.to_sym if Figaro.env.job_queue?

  # The test environment is used exclusively to run your application's
  # test suite. You never need to work with it otherwise. Remember that
  # your test database is "scratch space" for the test suite and is wiped
  # and recreated between test runs. Don't rely on the data there!
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Do not eager load code on boot. This avoids loading your whole application
  # just for the purpose of running a single test. If you are using a tool that
  # preloads Rails for running tests, you may have to set it to true.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Configure static asset server for tests with Cache-Control for performance.
  config.serve_static_files  = true
  config.static_cache_control = 'public, max-age=3600'

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Raise exceptions instead of rendering exception templates.
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false

  # Disable request forgery protection in test environment.
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false

  # Tell Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.
  # The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the
  # ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
  config.action_controller.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:5000' }
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:5000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
  # config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  # config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { address: 'localhost', port: '1025' }
  # Print deprecation notices to the stderr.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr

  config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

**Development.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.preview_path = "#{Rails.root}/app/mailers/previews"

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { address: 'localhost', port: '1025' }

  config.cache_store = :dalli_store
  # Use a different job queue
  config.active_job.queue_adapter = Figaro.env.job_queue.to_sym if Figaro.env.job_queue?

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  config.after_initialize do
    Bullet.enable = false
    Bullet.alert = true
    Bullet.console = true
    Bullet.rails_logger = true
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you include the related `spec`

Comment: @Marwen I've added it. It's pretty simple. Just goes to the page and clicks the link. I've added in my `test.rb` as well in case it's a configuration issue.

Comment: You have a typo in your spec. Change `rsign_in` to `sign_in`.

Comment: @NeilAtkinson `rsign_in` is a function that I'm using that simulates the process of a recruiter signing in. My main issue is the POST request made after clicking the link. The session gets reset for some reason thus causing the authentication to fail. Put a comment there to indicate the same.

Comment: When you click on '<3' this presumably hits a controller action. Are you relying on any config or environment variables in that controller action (or any before filters) that might be set in development but not in test?

Comment: @NeilAtkinson Nope. Not relying on any config. I've added my development.rb using that config in test.rb works but I can't figure out why. And why it doesn't work as is.

Comment: @kartikluke And you're not doing anything with `ActionController::Base.allow_forgery_protection` in any setup or before blocks?

Comment: @NeilAtkinson Nope I've never touched it before.

Comment: I'm wondering if you've got some impossibility short session expiry time (`expire_after`) resulting in the session timing out before the test completes. It could be something to do with the way you're simulating sign in in the tests. Can you post the `rsign_in` method definition?

Comment: @NeilAtkinson I'm sure it's not related to rsign_in it just fills in details in the sign in form and logs in. No there's no restriction on session expiry. It only expires on log out, I believe. I'm sorry if this is hard to figure out. I think the best thing to do would be to make a sample app and try and reproduce the behavior. I was just hoping someone who is aware of the internal workings could help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the error was coming from this line in my `test.rb`, was just trying to set the default host on my links to not be example.com. Not sure how this resulted in the bug I was experiencing. But after going through the config and trying to figure out why `development.rb` was working. This is what I got.

```
config.action_controller.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:5000' }
```

Thanks to everybody who helped me.